# Union of enums is not the same as enum?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I've some objects that share a lot of properties but then have a small subset that are different. They are differentiated by their ID which is one value from an enum. I would like to type these as subtypes of the same generic in order to take advantage of type guarding to know what properties are accessible.

Example:

```js
enum ItemIDs {
    ITEM_TYPE_1,
    ITEM_TYPE_2
}

// Generic item with shared properties
interface GenericItem<ID, Data> {
    id: ID
    data: Data
}

// Specific items where the 'data' property can be different shapes
type SpecificItemOne = GenericItem<ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_1, { content: string }>
type SpecificItemTwo = GenericItem<ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2, { amount: number }>

// Specific item is a union of all specific items
type SpecificItem = SpecificItemOne | SpecificItemTwo;

// Take item and test that typescript can work out what properties are available
// It works!
const testTypeGuard = (item: SpecificItem) => {
    if (item.id === ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_1) {
        item.data.content = ''
    } else if (item.id === ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2) {
        item.data.amount = 0;
    }
    return item;
}

// Try to create item where ID can be any from ID enum
const breakTypeGuard = (id: ItemIDs, data: any) => {
    // Type 'ItemIDs' is not assignable to type 'ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2'.
    // WHY
    testTypeGuard({ id, data });
}
```

Or [interactive on the ts site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20ItemIDs%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ITEM_TYPE_1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ITEM_TYPE_2%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Generic%20item%20with%20shared%20properties%0D%0Ainterface%20GenericItem%3CID%2C%20Data%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20ID%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20Data%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Specific%20items%20where%20the%20'data'%20property%20can%20be%20different%20shapes%0D%0Atype%20SpecificItemOne%20%3D%20GenericItem%3CItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_1%2C%20%7B%20content%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%0D%0Atype%20SpecificItemTwo%20%3D%20GenericItem%3CItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2%2C%20%7B%20amount%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Specific%20item%20is%20a%20union%20of%20all%20specific%20items%0D%0Atype%20SpecificItem%20%3D%20SpecificItemOne%20%7C%20SpecificItemTwo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Take%20item%20and%20test%20that%20typescript%20can%20work%20out%20what%20properties%20are%20available%0D%0A%2F%2F%20It%20works!%0D%0Aconst%20testTypeGuard%20%3D%20(item%3A%20SpecificItem)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(item.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item.data.content%20%3D%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(item.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item.data.amount%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20item%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Try%20to%20create%20item%20where%20ID%20can%20be%20any%20from%20ID%20enum%0D%0Aconst%20breakTypeGuard%20%3D%20(id%3A%20ItemIDs%2C%20data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'ItemIDs'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20WHY%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testTypeGuard(%7B%20id%2C%20data%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).

It seems to be saying that it cannot assign all of the enum values to a specific sub type. I don't see why this is a problem because it is in a union with other types that together do accept all the enum values.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you send `{ id, data }` as your parameter, this is considered as an **object literal type**.

```
// This function you declared is expecting a SpecificItem type parameter
// and you are sending an object literal type parameter
const testTypeGuard = (item: SpecificItem) => {
    if (item.id === ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_1) {
        item.data.content = ''
    } else if (item.id === ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2) {
        item.data.amount = 0;
    }
    return item;
}
```

Therefore, the types doesn't match and that's why you are getting an error.
What you need to do is send the object specifying the type, as suggested by @przemyslaw-pietrzak, like this:

```
// Try to create item where ID can be any from ID enum
const breakTypeGuard = (id: ItemIDs, data: any) => {
    // Type 'ItemIDs' is not assignable to type 'ItemIDs.ITEM_TYPE_2'.
    // WHY
    testTypeGuard({ id, data } as SpecificItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion is nothing wrong with your code. TS sometimes doesn't evaluate types (probably for performance issues).

If you want to make this code works i suggest to add `testTypeGuard({ id, data } as SpecificItem);`. It's not very unsafe because TS doesn't allow to map all types. E.g:

```js
let fn = (arg: 42) => 42;
fn(1); // Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type '42'.
fn(1 as number) // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '42'.
```